# Solve $\sin(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\pi/4$

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to solve (not approximate) the following trigonometric equation by hand? 
$$\sin(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\pi/4.$$

Comment: It can be a good idea to plug these sorts of questions into Wolfram Alpha, just to get a feel for the answer to which you're headed.  For example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%20%2B%20sin2x%20%3D%20pi%2F4&t=ff3tb01  Click the "exact form" link for the answers it gives--each one is about one screen-ful of text

Comment: @anorton: Solve by hand by computer :-)

Comment: Oh lol I certainly do NOT want to solve for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use $\arcsin$ (or $\sin^{-1}$), then yes.

This can be rewritten as a quartic in $\sin x$ which is theoretically solveable by hand (thought it might be very tedious).

Now you take the appropriate roots of those...

Comment: Oh ok. But by the way how did you make this into a solvable quartic equation?

Comment: @Ovi: $2 \sin x \cos x = \frac{\pi}{4} - \sin x$ and square it and use $\cos^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x$. Actually, that is only one quartic!